# Parameter List of Anonymous Function / Closure

Tags: php

Let's assume I have an anonymous function:

```
$my_function = function($par1, $par2) {
    // Do something
};
```

Is there a way to get a parameter list **without** executing the function in any way? Something like this:

```
$parameter_list = get_func_params($my_function);
```

The result should contain a list of all required function parameters:

```
Array (
    [0] => par1
    [1] => par2
)
```

### What code could `get_func_params` contain to return such an Array?

The background is that I use generic code that should check if the provided closure implements the required parameter logic.

*I don't want to solve this problem using Classes or Interfaces.*

Comment: Unless you question is about a specific PHP version (e.g. because a feature was only added there), it's enough to tag just [php] :)

Comment: @NikiC I understand. Though I think at least php-5.3 is appropriate, as closures aren't available prior to that version. Agree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
$my_function = function($par1, $par2) {
    // Do something
};

$reflection = new ReflectionFunction($my_function);
var_dump($reflection->getParameters());
```

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know about Reflection Functions. Thanks!